# Combine horizontally aligned polygons in a image

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, ocr

I have an image on which I am performing OCR using Google Vision API, I get a result which contains the polygon vertices of each word. After drawing the polygons the image looks like this.. [image: Ocr results]
I now want to combine the boxes that are horizontally aligned. For eg: (SALES ITEMS), (S000828749 MB Shorts 12.00),...,(Subtotal 146.00)

**Things I tried**:
I made a line from mid point of vertical edges and extended it to the image edge and counted how many polygons the line touches and color coded the polygon with same color as the line. I got an image something like this..
[image]
Not sure how to proceed and get the groups on single line..

Comment: Put all rectangles in a list. Sort the list first by `x` coordinate of top left corner and then by `y` coordinate of top left corner in ascending order.

Comment: Thats not correct. Sorting the list by `y` coordinate will change the order of list sorted by `x` so there will be no use of sorting by `x` and my final list will be sorted by `y`

Comment: can you provide the list of bounding boxes? It's a bit boring to manually measure the coordinates from your image. Something like [ ("SALES", 428, 34, 120, 40), ...]

Comment: Thanks @Harry.. But I have added the solved answer..

Comment: ok. thanks for sharing the answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by following method.
1. Each box will have a list of tags which are initialised to [].
2. Sort the boxes on x-coordinate.
3. Initialise tad to 0. Tags are just individual identifiers and our aim is to assign boxes on same line with same tags.
3. Iterate over each box.
4. If the tags list is empty, increment tag value and append it to the tags list for that box.
5. Iterate over all boxes for outer box and assign the same tag to each box that is touched by the axis line of outer box.
6. If tag list is not empty, take the maximum occurring tag in the tag list.
This is N^2 algorithm where N is number of boxes.